# jQuery: Match elements between .class and items // Combine nextAll() and nextUntil()

Tags: jquery, nextuntil

I have this DOM

```
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="a">match me not</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="c wrapper">c with some .wrapper</div>
<div class="a">match me!</div>
<div class="a">match me!</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="a">match me not</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

and need to match `.a` after `.wrapper` until the next `.c`

`nextAll()` matches everything after

`nextUntil()` only selects the last element

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/d4sSs/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe like this way

```
$(".wrapper").nextUntil('.c').filter(".a").addClass("matched");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4sSs/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".wrapper").nextUntil('.c').addClass("matched");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PAUQ6/

Comment: Thanks. That even fits my sepcified post with more .a and .c following